# Can you pass type aliases to an interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, higher-kinded-types

I'd like to write a TypeScript interface is generic over a type function instead of just a type. In other words, I want to write something like

```js
interface Foo<Functor> {
  bar: Functor<string>;
  baz: Functor<number>;
}
```

where `Functor` is some generic type alias I can pass in from the outside. Then I'll be able to make different kinds of `Foo` like this:

```js
type Identity<T> = T;
type Maybe<T> = T | undefined;
type List<T> = T[];

// All of the following would typecheck
const fooIdentity: Foo<Identity> = { bar: "abc", baz: 42 };
const fooMaybe: Foo<Maybe> = { bar: undefined, baz: undefined };
const fooList: Foo<List> = { bar: ["abc", "def"], baz: [42, 43] };
```

I've tried to find a way to make the compiler accept this but no luck, so I'm wondering if there's a trick I'm missing or if TypeScript just can't express this.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213 Not really sure if higher kind types are in Typescript. Towards the end of the discussion, they seems to be working on it.

Comment: The TS developers prioritize and give attention according to issue upvotes, so give higher kinded types an  , if you want this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am late to the party but there is now a comprehensive solution to this problem on the user end, so I thought I might share it.

Details of how it works can be found [here](https://github.com/geoffreytools/free-types/blob/public/doc/Guide.md), but in a nutshell we exploit the fact that interfaces can receive arguments through intersection:

```js
type Type = { type: unknown, 0: unknown }

interface $Maybe extends Type { type: this[0] | undefined }

type apply<$T extends Type, V> = ($T & [V])['type']

type Maybe3 = apply<$Maybe, 3> // 3 | undefined
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8qkgLigVwHYGtcB7Ad1wBooAGLPQ03KAXwFgAodgS12AgCcAZgEMAxtAAkAWSEgARtAgAPXrgAmAZ1jwUaeFmAALTuoDaVALpQAPjjUQB3CKubt26aELBgANiAA84jBQSioaWpCUAGoAfFBIABSBUABkUCaR5gCUJgDk7jnmrmzuUNJyEADMcVCePv5SMvKUFbEA9K1QVTZ4qvaOqkA)

Notice how we were able to detach the type constructor from its value.

This pattern is very flexible and enabled the creation of the library [free-types](https://github.com/geoffreytools/free-types) which adds a bunch of features, like support for type constraints, partial application, composition, variadicity, optionality, inference, etc.

---

So what can we do with your use case?

Technically there are ready-made types for `List` and `Identity`, so we only need to define `$Maybe`. You can also set `Identity` as a default parameter to `Foo`, which is pretty convenient.

```js
import { Type, apply, free } from 'free-types';

interface Foo<$T extends Type<1> = free.Id> {
    bar: apply<$T, [string]>;
    baz: apply<$T, [number]>;
}

interface $Maybe extends Type<1> { type: this[0] | undefined }
    
const fooIdentity: Foo = { bar: "abc", baz: 42 };
const fooMaybe: Foo<$Maybe> = { bar: undefined, baz: undefined };
const fooList: Foo<free.Array> = { bar: ["abc", "def"], baz: [42, 43] };
```

You may want to check that your type constructors can actually accept `string | number`.

```js
import { Type, apply, free, Contra } from 'free-types';

interface Foo<$T extends Type<1> & Contra<$T, Type<[string | number]>> = free.Id> {
//                       ------------------- hacked contravariance
    bar: apply<$T, [string]>;
    baz: apply<$T, [number]>;
}
    
const fooIdentity: Foo = { bar: "abc", baz: 42 };
const fooMaybe: Foo<$Maybe> = { bar: undefined, baz: undefined };
const fooList: Foo<free.Array> = { bar: ["abc", "def"], baz: [42, 43] };

// @ts-expect-error: WeakSet expects object, not string | number
type FooWeakSet = Foo<free.WeakSet>;
```

You may also want to check that your type is actually a Functor (which is only the case for `List` here).

```js
import { Type, apply, free, Contra } from 'free-types';

interface Foo<$T extends $Functor> {
    bar: apply<$T, [string]>;
    baz: apply<$T, [number]>;
}

type $Functor = Type<1, {
    map: (f: (...args: any[]) => unknown) => unknown
}>

// @ts-expect-error: Identity lacks a map method
const fooIdentity: Foo<free.Id> = { bar: "abc", baz: 42 };

// @ts-expect-error: our Maybe lacks a map method
const fooMaybe: Foo<$Maybe> = { bar: undefined, baz: undefined };

const fooList: Foo<free.Array> = { bar: ["abc", "def"], baz: [42, 43] };
```

Finally, If you don't like having 2 versions of the same type, you can conflate them into one.

```js
import { Type, apply, free, $Alter } from 'free-types';

interface Foo<$T extends Type<1>> {
    bar: apply<$T, [string]>;
    baz: apply<$T, [number]>;
}

type Array<T = never> = $Alter<free.Array, [T]>

type Array1 = Array<1> // 1[]

const fooList: Foo<Array> = { bar: ["abc", "def"], baz: [42, 43] };
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQJ5gKYBo4EMxgA2qOAZlBtnAMIQB2MUuOAJAIKEwZRwC+c5CCDgBycpQC0MdBgDOIgNwBYAFCqA9OpQYAxgAs6wHbkLE4MPdwx4KcCrgAmqCSEfXpmWQOhwABgBlgWRhfPDoHPwBJBwwGYGlfDS1ZCDgAd2t6MzpKCJhUmNJgHL8WAFlcVAAjDF8AOlVVYq4oUlwda3LKmrgMAA8ucK80TAAeAEYAPkRzGQAucz0ggG0ABgBdOAAfOABXcIwinIjeRpUEVTgruE04AE0IXbhjOjxCFLhZDHhfaNiYeKoUK4Ly4OCFXC7ThwMC4Jggb7cHBpJb6OBBGEUGDSZ70ABusWA-zO13RDG4bQ6cAAYhAIKMWMhegNYg5hjIJtMALwCCgYOrRaYXFSk0lVOELfBEVAM5A4ZbBKDFADm60myhFoqu4oAXpKCMRZfK6LsQDUoGqNaTTpqrpdrjp6MFvBA-nFpAtaakeUhxVAFgAiXBVHQBnC6hYAFgATHwrQ6nfBSHSKtUMJ66QzUzVuTM-Qt9oVihgHOHcHq9gcjiW4-aro66M7kxBAsEM-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-Ss0dMpjWt1tJM2SrKvp2ut23rzgFzHedvBXbAd2LC9n2mxTbpXLgjyczD7yI+C-zMtr45Y6Lv2ouDvk6niypEsHZKo-HSdp0ChY52jBdl1jzbbmpYoPxIO3SGurcHHoER4EIYBuI43A8UA2MCRfYAnU6hfQc+XAEVmTAsA3G7nn3XE6FIJ2uEWDBhGaVJ6AwVRBauVHWnRm5eC-RELsjGFMYm9EybKUZtTNaUDyz6mlIzZm8DribVJFNTuMomQ8hyPvXM7BODcFiu3bB8pkBqhNpfaw2Dxg82wZyG4WhxiK2oXpF0rcgHYO7hHXuNl+7pUHopEeY88qqF4EAA)

Comment: Awesome and horrifying. I'll accept this in honor of your effort, but I'll probably never use this unless TS adds native support that's more ergonomic.

Comment: Yes I think the best use case currently is library design. One can expose an extensible type like `Foo` which does all the nasty type checking and users only write hooks for it. They don't need to know about `Contra`, `apply`, `$Alter`, etc. The only alternative is passing a string to `Foo` and using it as a key to index an object type, which requires module augmentation if we want users to write their own hooks. It is more awkward as there are more indirections, and it is less safe especially across packages. The package `type-lenses` is an example of a more user-friendly setup.