# Infer Object Generic from its propery (return function type)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to make an interface that can infers a type `T` from the return value of the function `data` so the function `step` can receive as a parameter the type of `this`.

Something like this:

```
type DefInstance = {
    
    x : number,
    y : number,
};

type StateInstance<T> = {
    data : () => T,
    step : (this : DefInstance & T, turn : number) => boolean,
};

const instance : StateInstance<{
    f : number
}> = {
    data : () => ({
        f : 0,
    }),
    step : function(turn){
        this.f++;
        
        if(this.f > 3){
            this.x += 1;
            this.f = 0;
        }
        console.log(`move on turn ${turn}`);          
        return true;
    }
}
```

But without having to specify the type.

```
/*
  stuff from above
*/

//so it looks like this
const instance : StateInstance = {
    data : () => ({
        f : 0,
    }), //here i define the function and the return value
    step : function(turn){
        this.f++; //here i access the members described in the return value of data
        
        if(this.f > 3){
            this.x += 1;
            this.f = 0;
        }
        console.log(`move on turn ${turn}`);          
        return true;
    }
}
```

similar to what is made in Vue.js (v3) with the `data` function, where all methods can access the members of the state of the component

```
/*vue stuff*/
export default defineComponent({
  data : () => ({ count : 10 }),
  methods : {
    countUp() { this.count++; } //Autocompleted property `count` when access `this`
  }
})
```

I know that Vue uses a function (that uses lots of generics behind), but i want to know **how to to do it using only a type (or interface)** (if posible). Or, if its only doable using functions, **how to do it with a function.**

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: With a function it's easy: `function magic<T>(i: StateInstance<T>): StateInstance<T> { return i; }`

Comment: I second vera's comment. It is just as terse as what you wanted to write. I am not even sure there is a runtime cost: the JIT would probably optimise that id function away. Finally, you are creating an object anyway, it is common to have a constructor or a factory function for an object, whereas defining an object with behaviour the way you did is a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reuse that `magic` function vera mentioned, you can make the type constructor generic:

```js
import { apply } from 'free-types'

const of = <$T extends Type<1>>() => <T>(i: apply<$T, [T]>) => i;

const State = of<$StateInstance>();

const instance = State({
    data : () => ({
        f : 0,
    }), //here i define the function and the return value
    step : function(turn){
        this.f++; //here i access the members described in the return value of data
        
        if(this.f > 3){
            this.x += 1;
            this.f = 0;
        }
        console.log(`move on turn ${turn}`);          
        return true;
    }
})
```

`$StateInstance` can be defined like so

```js
interface $StateInstance extends Type<1> {
   type: StateInstance<this[0]>
}
```

Or, if you don't need `StateInstance` for anything else:

```js
interface $StateInstance extends Type<1> {
    type: { [K in 'data'|'step']: this[K] }
    data : () => this[0],
    step : (this : DefInstance & this[0], turn : number) => boolean,
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQJ5gKYBo4EMxgA2qcAvnAGZQQhwDkVGGAtDOhgM50BQ3bmcACIYKASQB2HGLnEBjDHAC8ibnDVwAHnABcccQFcQAIwxQsq9SV0Hjp86QDcvfgoDK0mBglSZ8gDzIAHxKKupwACa40jpwABQAlErByOZhUhhgMbEwABbAHDHCYpLScgoAZCg4MPpQ4jE2JlCJisFGEBCEGDL2TtzA4p5QFLjycAAk7lFeJb4KGBqe4uEFaJh+AIzBCBZwLrpTnt6l-rn5ANoADAC6gdykvLIQJXAQFCF+48hwC0srKOxNoFAgkknAAiDgLp8ERUJ8UnBzshbi1gsA+k8XocFMo3p9scc5iD4hjnlI4AMfGUQtjYjswpForpQa04vSwup3rpLql1KR4jgAPSCnKmBTACIiAYKXIKCj6OQwYDPPDLPaiuBQDA1OpwABuuEI+gwuzg6UyunliuV4mytXE8XZHPV+QAdBQANQehxwYWirUUvCyeQcAqyuAgDC2KAFcKcWRQYAmcIU+rhrU6+oGo0KN4RKK4U1hIvqYAUbJ5DjuuDBADMjpLzrOVa0HuUGyczqblerykuna7Dy7cExHE6GFdhAgAHNYgADEAQPW5tP2iYITOkOck4dqRua7VrmBQY0DtQPflAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for including a link to an example, it works exactly as i need, but could you explain what module (or library) is `'free-types'`
i seem to be unable to import them as a preinstaled dependency

Comment: Nvm, i think i found it, could you confirm [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-types) is the library you are using

Comment: Yes, you can find a lightweight implementation of `Type` and `apply` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65730766/can-you-pass-type-aliases-to-an-interface-in-typescript/74678125#74678125) to get rid of the dependency, although you should probably tighten type safety a little bit and make use of the library's support for type constraints as shown in [this example](https://tsplay.dev/N727nw), because the argument to `StateInstance` should at least extend `object`

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrDg0W) instead? At no point do you make sure `x`, `y`, and `f` are initialised. An [alternate design](https://tsplay.dev/mM8orN) using a class may work better, although the dynamic field would force you to use trickeries as well and would have to be considered as private.